# How to call the Firestore's Grandchild (Document/Child/Grandchild) data?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to call the data from Firestore document's grandchild context in Flutter. 
As I know only how to call the data from Children context.

I can't post the picture so... I'll just Explain that
my Firestore looks like this

```
collection        document       context

Example1 >        e1 >          
                                 class:"A1"

                              v  who
                                 v  0
                                    name:"Jack"
                                    sex:"boy"
                                 v  1
                                    name:"Mike"
                                    sex:"boy"
```

I already know how to call the "class" using code below, but the question is how to call "name" and "sex" under the 'who'.

```py
    body: StreamBuilder(
     stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Example1').snapshots(),
     builder: (context, snapshot) {
       if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
         return ListView.builder(
           itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
           itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
           _buildListItem(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]),
            );
     }),
```

Thank you for answering my question

Answer (score 0):

```
body: StreamBuilder(
     stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Example1/e1/who').snapshots(),
     builder: (context, snapshot) {
       if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
         return ListView.builder(
           itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
           itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
           _buildListItem(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]),
            );
     }),
```

You can use the path in the collection parameter

Comment: What do you get

Comment: Nothing ! No data